# Diff eqs can be solved?

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve a pair of coupled differential equations, but am having trouble making DSolve evaluate my equations.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
DSolve[{m x''[t] == m (a + x[t]) (θ'[t])^2 + m g Cos[θ[t]] - k x[t], 
    m (a + x[t]) θ''[t] + 2 m x'[t] θ'[t] == -m g Sin[θ[t]]}, {x, θ}, t] // FullSimplify
```

When I run the code, I simply get the original (slightly simplified) version of whats above, with no error messages. Can someone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: A brief literature search confirms that there is no known closed form solution of the Pendulum on a Spring problem except in the limit of small θ.  See, for instance, [these notes](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~tlakoba/AppliedUGMath/notes/lecture_7.pdf).  Hence, a numerical solution should be tried, using `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 3):

A sample numerical solution is

```
m = 1; a = 1; g = 1; k = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{m x''[t] == m (a + x[t]) (θ'[t])^2 + m g Cos[θ[t]] - k x[t], 
            m (a + x[t]) θ''[t] + 2 m x'[t] θ'[t] == -m g Sin[θ[t]], 
            x[0] == 1, θ[0] == .2, x'[0] == 1, θ'[0] == 0}, {x, θ}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], θ[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: This should be Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], \[Theta][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}], not Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], 0[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]

Comment: @andandandand  Thanks for identifying the typo, which I have corrected.